# Should I trust Redis for data integrity?

Tags: performance, redis, data-integrity

In my current project, I have PostgreSQL as my master DB, and Redis as kind of a slave, e.g., when some user adds another as a friend, first the relationship will be stored in PostgreSQL and then a friend list in Redis will be updated. When some user's friend list is requested, it will be pulled out of Redis instead of PostgreSQL.

The question is: when I update the friend list in Redis, should I get a fresh copy outof PostgreSQL, and replace the old list in Redis with the new one or should I keep the old list and simply SADD the userid into the list? The latter is of course best for performance, but intuitively the former does a better job in keep the data integrity? And if something like Celery is used, is the second method worth the risk?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Redis. When you are writing to two databases, a lot of things can go wrong even if both of them individually guarantee data integrity.

For the sake of discussion, replace Redis with MySQL in your question, and ask yourself - will data integrity be compromised?

You may have written to Postgres and then your process can die without writing to MySQL. Or perhaps there is a network outage. Or perhaps MySQL is down. In all these cases, Postgres and MySQL would start to differ.

It does not matter whether you replace the entire record or simply add one row. Both can lead to data corruption.

If you are concerned with data integrity, keep data in a single authoritative system. Otherwise, you would need a [two phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

Comment: +1 - agree... and further point out/notice that the choice to use redis as the slave instead of the master in this scenario seems odd to me.  if scalability trumps consistency requirements in this scenario why not use redis as the authoritative source (setting up vertically sharded keyspaces if a single server won't handle the load) and then replicate to cassandra or some other horizontally-scalable store?

Comment: @Sripathi, I'm fully aware of the problem you mentioned, no matter with method I choose, data corruption will occur at the same rate, but is this the only place where corruption occurs? Since Redis is not ACID compliant, I'd like to know how frequently should I reconstruct its data from the master, or is it practical to treat it as an ACID one(in this specific senario, of course)?

Comment: @codemonkey In fact I need consistency, so I choose Postgres as master, since Redis data can be reconstructed from it, theoretically the data sent to users can be made 'almost' consistent.

Comment: redis is consistent when run as a single server.  writes are atomic and serialized.  you can even enforce transactions and rollback with a little work.  eventual consistency and horizontal scalability is better served by something like cassandra.  now if by "consistent" you actually mean "durable" that's a different conversation... one that can be informed by: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate how important consistency is to your application and take things from there.  It doesn't sound like anyone's cry if you loose a commit.  You could have a background process that reads data from PostgreSQL and pushes it back into Redis, eventually cleaning up any inconsistencies.  Alternatively, you could look at read slave PostgreSQL instances replicating from the write master.  This would get you better read scalability using well tested synchronization technology.

Comment: Yes, I want to make a tradeoff between consistency and performance, that's why I choose Redis to be the slave. Doing a constant data iteration/reconstruction seems safe but a bit resource demanding? In fact, how badly Redis needs this is the answer I want to know.